# VBScript to change the Macro security in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wanted to know how I can modify the security level in Microsoft Word using a VBScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean **macro** security?

My assumption is that it isn't possible to programmatically change macro security levels in Microsoft Word. What would stop a malicious script from doing the same?

It's a manual process for a reason; you need to *explicitly* change macro security levels.

Perhaps if you explain what you are trying to accomplish and **why** that requires a different security level, I or someone else can provide a better answer.

Comment: We recently deployed a .DOT file which has a Macro and the Macro has to change the security to LOW for it to work. We have hundreds of users calling local IT for support so I wanted to programatically change it (even if its a registry change)

Comment: What is the macro doing that it requires low security?

Comment: To add to what @JP has already said. Generally a medium security setting should allow the template to function. It will simply prompt the user on whether or not they want to enable macros. Setting Macro Security to low is a invitation to collect viruses.